# How to use PHP in title of webpage

Tags: php, html, echo, title

I have a simple php  :

```
<title><?php echo $user["right_name"] ;echo  $user["surname"]; ?></title>
```

But.. what it does, it prints users name and surname in title of webpage, but without spaces, how to fix that and make space between name and surname?

Thanks :)

Comment: this is easy as pie.

Comment: <?php echo $user["right_name"].' '.$user["surname"]; ?>

Comment: Thanks a lot guys, You save lot of time :)

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_strings.htm

Answer (score 0):

```
<title><?php echo $user["right_name"] . ' ' . $user["surname"]; ?></title>
```

Answer (score 0):

Concatenate a space character between them:

```
<title><?php echo $user["right_name"]." ".$user["surname"]; ?></title>
```